# How do I find references to a given record for a specific field in the referencing record in OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb, nosql

If I have a class `A` with attributes `A.a` and `A.b`, which are both LINKs that can reference other records of class A, how do I - for a given instance of A - find all the other records that reference this instance in their attribute `A.a` but *not* `A.b`?

[Here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/SQL-Find-References) I just found how to find *all* referencing records, not distinguishing by which field is used to reference a given record.

Example for clarification: Let's say there's a class `Person` with attributes `personalTrainer` and `partner`, which are other `Person`s. For a given `Person`, how do I find all other `Person`s (hopefully 0 or 1) which have this one as their `partner`, but not their `personalTrainer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use GraphAPI where all links are automatically managed by OrientDB and you can always cross your relationships in both directions.